# Link combobox with database values

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm trying to link a ComboBox with Database values but after I debug it gave me an error related System.IndexOutOfRangeException. Here it is the following code that I'm using right now

```
SQLCon = New SqlConnection
    SQLCon.ConnectionString = "..."
    Try
        SQLCon.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "SELECT Filetype FROM infofile GROUP BY Filetype"
        SqlCmd = New SqlCommand(Query, SQLCon)
        SQLDataReader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        While SQLDataReader.Read
            Dim fileType = SQLDataReader.GetString(1)
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(fileType)
        End While
        SQLCon.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        SQLCon.Dispose()
    End Try
```

The error occurs `Dim fileType = SQLDataReader.GetString(1)`

I know why this is happening, because if I use the `SELECT * FROM infofile` it works but I want to group it instead of displays all the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetString()` takes a 0-based index number. You are asking it to give you the second element (index number 1) when you only selected one column.  There is no second element.  Change the 1 to a 0.

More info on the `GetString` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I got it. I solver my problem, I've used GetString(0)

Comment: Can you help me with another thing?

Comment: Post another question, someone will be able to help you, whether it's me or not.